# The efficiency about big data into node on AgensGraph

Tags: indexing, agens-graph, wide-column-store

As far as I know, wide-column cannot be applicable. 
But is there a difference in efficiency to put big data into the node? 
I'd like to put an index to distinguish the value and want to know the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

"There are few efficiency considerations when putting big data into nodes (accurately property). Search filtering may become slower due to search scope and size increases. Changes may result in overhead such as wal log. 
Although it's difficult to determine how much big data you have, but I think you should save it as a file and save its description as property type. Information saved in the property can reduce access expense by the creation of a seperate property index. "